# Weird rotation behavior while georeferencing in QGIS 3.30.1

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, rotate

[image]

I am working with a project which is rotated 20 Degrees (see lower right corner of screenshot). I had someone from Fiverr render out a relief map for me to put in as a background. They supplied me with a GeoTIFF that has though been sloppily georeferenced. It kinda fits, but not very well. I wanted to fit it properly so I've been GCP points all evening. Here's the catch; the GeoTIFF is rotated 20 degrees by the author (like my project) however, the Georeferencer seems to not be aware of this, thus whenever I start the georeferencing process, the map loads, turned exactly 20 degrees wrong. I have played with all the settings but to no avail. I have tried resetting the project rotation. Doesn't work. I have tried rotating the map in the Georeferencer panel, doesn't work. The Geotiff file seems to not be editable, which means, I can't manually rotate it the 20 degrees. How can I solve this?

My QGIS version is 3.30.1

Comment: What version of QGIS there is a known bug in certain versions. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51814#issuecomment-1426684880

Comment: Its version 3.30.1. Any fix known or workaround?